# My kubernetes pods are Evicting with ephemeral-storage issue

Tags: kubernetes, logrotate, ephemeral-storage

I am running a k8 cluster with 8 workers and 3 master nodes. And my pods are evicting repetively with the ephemeral storage issues.
Below is the error I am getting on Evicted pods:

```
Message:        The node was low on resource: ephemeral-storage. Container xpaas-logger was using 30108Ki, which exceeds its request of 0. Container wso2am-gateway-am was using 406468Ki, which exceeds its request of 0.
```

To overcome the above error, I have added ephemeral storage limits and request to my namespace.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: LimitRange
metadata:
  name: ephemeral-storage-limit-range
spec:
  limits:
  - default:
      ephemeral-storage: 2Gi
    defaultRequest:
      ephemeral-storage: 130Mi
    type: Container
```

Even after adding the above limits and requests to my namespace, my pod is reaching its limits and then evicting.

```
Message:        Pod ephemeral local storage usage exceeds the total limit of containers 2Gi.
```

How can I monitor my ephemeral storage, where does it store on my instance?
How can I set the docker logrotate to my ephemeral storage based on size? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

"Ephemeral storage" here refers to space being used in the container filesystem that's not in a volume.  Something inside your process is using a lot of local disk space.  In the abstract this is relatively easy to debug: use `kubectl exec` to get a shell in the pod, and then use normal Unix commands like `du` to find where the space is going.  Since it's space inside the pod, it's not directly accessible from the nodes, and you probably can't use tools like `logrotate` to try to manage it.

One specific cause of this I've run into in the past is processes configured to log to a file.  In Kubernetes you should generally set your logging setup to log to stdout instead.  This avoids this specific ephemeral-storage problem, but also avoids a number of practical issues around actually getting the log file out of the pod.  `kubectl logs` will show you these logs and you can set up cluster-level tooling to export them to another system.